# How do i count the numbers in a given range who's digits sum is divisible by 3

Tags: c++

For example if we take
139 141
then
The numbers are 139, 140 and 141. Their sum of digits is 13, 5 and 6 respectively. So, only 141 is the number that has its sum of digits divisible by 3.

Comment: What have you tried? Always better to add your attempted code here

Comment: I strongly recommend that you do a better effort on your homework by yourself, at least to some degree (which I don't see you having done, given that you haven't posted any code). You won't be able to ask SO in your exam.

Answer (score 0):

This may be cheating, but if a number is divisible by 3, so is the sum of its digits. This means you don't really need to sum the digits, you could just check if the number is divisible by 3 directly:

```cpp
int countSumDigitsDivisibleByThree(int minRange, intMaxRange) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = minRange; i <= maxRange; ++i) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: That is very true. I hadn't considered that. If this *is* cheating, have a look at my solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do is to iterate over each one of the numbers and sum up its digits, then check if the sum is divisible by 3. I would've done something like this -

```cpp
int getSumOfDigits(int num){
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 0){
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = START_OF_RANGE; i <= END_OF_RANGE; i++){
        if (sumOfDigits(i) % 3 == 0){
            count++;
        }
    }
    // count is the number of numbers whose sum of digits is divisible by 3.
    return 0;
}
```